# MyBB Forum Setup

Tags: php, mybb, forums

I'm currently trying to setup myBB forums on my website. I go to the install directory but it just shows all my files instead of showing the setup to install. Also, when I try to open the install/index.php, it just says file not found although you can clearly see that it's there. If you could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the install directory on my website: http://blacksunswg.com/forums/install/

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a localhost, you need to put the files that are inside of "Upload" into your htdocs folder and then open your localhost in your browser for the installation to pop up

Comment: "If you are running a localhost" — The question provides a URL that is not localhost